# Prev/Next button sql query

Tags: sql, limit

I have a table data with following columns:

    |-a-|-b-|-text-|

    |-1-|-1-|-text-|

    |-1-|-2-|-text-|

    **|-1-|-3-|-text-|**

    |-2-|-1-|-text-|

    |-2-|-2-|-text-|

    |-2-|-3-|-text-|

    |-2-|-4-|-text-|

e.g. I am on 3rd record ($current - in **bold**), I need to make sql query to move to (2, 1).

I have the query as below:

```
$previous = "SELECT a, b FROM `table` WHERE a <= $current_a AND b < $current_b ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC LIMIT 1";
$next = "SELECT a, b FROM `table` WHERE a >= $current_a AND b > $current_b ORDER BY a ASC, b ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Though however next goes to (2, 4) instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: $current_b is 3 so it's not that strange that it moves to (2, 4) instead of (2, 1). (2, 4) is the only one that comes after (1, 3) according to your SQL so you have to think of some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a condition that handles the two cases separately; when the *a* values are the same, and when they are different:

```
where (a = @current_a and b > @current_b) or (a > @current_a)
```

You need that for the previous item also:

```
where (a = @current_a and b < @current_b) ro (a < @current_a)
```